# how to remove space

Tags: mysql, bash

1st command

```
RELAY_MASTER_LOG_FILE=$(mysql -uroot -p1234 -e 'show slave status \G'| grep 'Relay_Master_Log_File' |cut -d: -f2|tr -d " ")
```

```
echo $RELAY_MASTER_LOG_FILE
```

result

```
node-bin.000002
```

(no space before the variable value)

but when I try to execute this command

```
SET_REPLICATION_PARAMS="MASTER_LOG_FILE='$RELAY_MASTER_LOG_FILE'"
```

I get this result

```
MASTER_LOG_FILE=' node-bin.000002'
```

there is a space before the variable value

Comment: Are you definitely sure the first output does not have a space or hidden characters? Write it to a file `echo $VAR_NAME > file.txt` and check the file size.

Comment: yes I am sure.. I'll try your advised

Comment: what will I do after checking the file size?

Comment: Please make sure to enclose the variable with double quotes as `echo "$VAR_NAME" > file.txt`. Then please post the result of `xxd file.txt` to see if any odd character is included.

Comment: `echo $RELAY_MASTER_LOG_FILE` is not a good way to see what a variable contains. Among other things, it *will* remove spaces at the beginning of the value; see ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). Even with double-quotes, it can still be misleading in a number of ways. `declare -p RELAY_MASTER_LOG_FILE` tends to be much clearer. Putting `set -x` before the problematic section to get an execution trace is another good method.

Comment: @tshiono this is the result

MASTER_LOG_FILE='
node-bin.000002'

Comment: What about the result of `xxd file.txt`? `xxd` is a command name.

Comment: 00000000: 4d41 5354 4552 5f4c 4f47 5f46 494c 453d  MASTER_LOG_FILE=
00000010: 270a 6e6f 6465 2d62 696e 2e30 3030 3030  '.node-bin.00000
00000020: 3227 0a

Comment: I'm sorry @RenaudPacalet but I don't follow you

Comment: @RaymundDalagan What do you mean? If you want to comment my answer please do it in my answer's comments. And if you have a specific question please try to be accurate. _I don't follow you_ is not very informative.

Comment: @RaymundDalagan From that `xxd` output, the variable actually contains a newline character (the `0a` near the beginning of the second line of output); when you use the variable without double-quotes, it's treated as whitespace and therefore equivalent to a space character. Lesson: double-quote your variables to avoid confusion like this. As for why it's there, I don't know. I'd have to see the exact output from that `mysql` command, and maybe `mysql ... | grep 'Relay_Master_Log_File'` (in particular, does it output a blank line before the one with the filename on it?).

Answer (score 2):

`echo $var` first expands variable `var` and then output the resulting words,  separated by spaces, followed by a newline. So if there are leading or trailing spaces `echo` eats them because they are located before/after the first/last word. If you want to preserve the spaces double quote the variable expansion to produce one single word, including the spaces:

```sh
$ a=' node-bin.000002`
$ echo $a
node-bin.000002
$ echo "$a"
 node-bin.000002
```

If you want to remove the leading space from the variable value use a pattern substitution: `a="${a# }"`. Example:

```sh
$ a=' node-bin.000002`
$ b="MASTER_LOG_FILE='$a'"
$ echo "$b"
MASTER_LOG_FILE=' node-bin.000002'
$ a="${a# }"
$ b="MASTER_LOG_FILE='$a'"
$ echo "$b"
MASTER_LOG_FILE='node-bin.000002'
```